# What is faster in average, btree or hash table?

Tags: data-structures, hashtable, time-complexity, b-tree

I try compare b-tree and hash table look up time complexity.

B-tree needs `log_b(n)` operations and `log_b(n) <= b` if `n <= b^b` so for `b = 10` it is `10^10` at any case and I have `10` operations for look up.
Hash table needs `1` operation for look up in average. But if I have a `10^10` keys and size of my hash table is `10^10/10` then it will be `10` operation for look up in average case (for separate chaining), or not?

I think it is a lot theoretical. I want know, what is better in practice? why?

Comment: Which is better, a gorilla or a shark?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> what is better in practice?

It depends.

A b-tree is always *O(log n)* performance.

A hash table is *O(1)* (much better than the b-tree) with

1. A good hash function for your data.
2. Enough hash buckets.

If those criteria are not met then the hash table will tend towards *O(n)* (ie. much worse than the b-tree).

Summary: good hash function: hash table will usually be better. A b-tree is consistent without needing a hash function.

In practice *n* is not large, and even a generic hash will be good enough to achieve close enough to *O(1)* that spending time on the question is a pointless optimisation.

***Real answer: until you measure performance and determine that data structure lookup times are significant put your optimisation effort where your users will see a significant difference.***

Comment: It also depends on if you want an ordered-map or an unordered one.

Comment: a hash table is O(n) much worse that b-tree. But for average case what you mentioned is true.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot easily compare them because they provide different functionality. The hash table is a key-value store while the tree also allows lookup based on order (previous/next, etc).

Rule of thumb: If you want to use them for a specific task, just **measure** which one is better.

Note: those numbers are huge, does it even fit into the memory of your machine?